# change color of text in a RadioButton of QML

Tags: qt, qml

Using Qt Quick Controls 1, is there a way to change the color of the text of a RadioButton in QML?

I want to change it to white, because my background is black and can't find a way to do it.

[image: qml]

```
                RowLayout {
                    RadioButton {
                        width:15
                        height:15
                        text: "xlsx"
                        checked: true
                    }
                    RadioButton {
                        width:15
                        height:15
                        text: "Bottom"
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are the 2 answers below not what you're looking for? Do you want to set the color dynamically after creation? please explain

Comment: Hello @bardao no i want it to have customization at creation. Maybe version 2 of controls solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Qt Quick Controls 2, you should create your own `RadioButton` component with a custom `contentItem`:

```
RadioButton {
    id: control
    width: 15
    height: 15
    text: "xlsx"
    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        color: "white"
        leftPadding: control.indicator.width + control.spacing
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

See the full example in the doc: [Customizing RadioButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-radiobutton).

For Qt Quick Controls 1 see @Roya Ghasemzadeh answer.

Comment: This might be the solution i'm looking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a style for your radioButton. for example for the second radioButton you can have:

```
    RadioButton 
        {
            width:15
            height:15


            style: RadioButtonStyle
            {
                label: Text
                {
                    color: "white";
                    text: "Bottom"

                }                                   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

radioButton->setStyleSheet("QRadioButton{ background-color : black; color : white; }");

Comment: Is there something like this for qml?